# Magento 2.3 : How to implement declarative schema in custom module

Tags: magento2.3, database-schema

I install the magento 2.3 and I'm creating custom module.

But, I don't know how to create custom database table in magento 2.3 version.

Comment: database Or custom table in Magento database?

Comment: Here you can have more idea of [Create table using Declarative Schema in Magento 2.3](https://stagebit.com/magento-2/declarative-schema-magento-2-3/)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

First of all, create `db_schema.xml` file inside `/RH/Helloworld/etc` and write the following code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="rh_helloworld" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="RH Helloworld">
        <column xsi:type="smallint" name="id" padding="6" unsigned="false" nullable="false" identity="true" comment="ID"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="author_name" nullable="false" length="25" comment="Name"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="email" nullable="false" length="25" comment="Email"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="description" nullable="false" length="255" comment="Descrition"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
            <column name="id"/>
        </constraint>
    </table>
</schema>
```

- `<table> .. </table>` = "Use for create and set table name"
- `<column> .. </column>` = "Use for create and set column of the table"
- `<constraint> .. </constraint>` = "Use for set constraint as like
  primary key, foreign key, unique key etc."

Before running the upgrade command you need to add your schema to `db_whitelist_schema.json` file by running the following command :

```
php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=RH_Helloworld
```

Now, there are `db_whitelist_schema.json` file will be create in `/RH/Helloworld/etc` folder.

Now, run `php bin/magento s:up`

Table will be create inside database.

=>  If you want to renaming a column, you need to set below line in your `db_schema.xml` at appropriate column :

```
<column xsi:type="varchar" name="customer_email" onCreate="migrateDataFrom(email)" on_update="false" nullable="false" default="" comment="Customer Email"/>
```

here, **name = "new column name"** and **onCreate="migrateDataFrom()" = "old column name"**

=> If you want to drop table, then you can either remove entire table node from xml file or you can set disabled attribute to true as like below line in your `db_schema.xml` :

```
<table name="rh_helloworld" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="RH Helloworld" disabled="true">
 ..
 </table>
```

For more details, You can [check here](https://www.rohanhapani.com/magento-2-3-create-a-new-table-using-declarative-schema/).

Hope, It will helpful for you.

Comment: Good one @Rohan

Comment: Nice explanation..... Thank you so much.... It is really helpful....

Comment: Happy to help !! Happy coding :) & Thank You @RamkishanSuthar

Comment: Why we need to generate db_whitelist_schema.json ?

Comment: @RohanHapani How can I create custom product attribute in Magento 2.3.0 using custom extension ?

Comment: How to convert UpgradeSchema, InstallData to Declarative schema?

Comment: it shows reference id is missing in constraint

Comment: @RohanHapani, I have installed 2.3.3, It is still working with InstallSchema, InstallData,.. etc, is there any major difference in Declarative schema?

Comment: getting this error. Element 'column', attribute 'length': The attribute 'length' is not allowed @RohanHapani

Answer (score 13):

Create file named as **db_schema.xml** under etc folder in your any custom module.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="books_data" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="Book Table">
        <column xsi:type="smallint" name="id" padding="6" unsigned="false" nullable="false" identity="true" comment="BOOK ID"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="book_name" nullable="false" length="255" comment="Book Name"/>
        <column xsi:type="int" name="author" unsigned="true" nullable="true" identity="false" default="" comment="Author"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="isbn_no" nullable="true" comment="ISBN No"/>
        <column xsi:type="timestamp" name="publish_date" on_update="false" nullable="false" default="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
                comment="Publish Date"/>
      <column xsi:type="varchar" name="language" nullable="true" comment="Language"/>
         <column xsi:type="decimal" name="mrp" scale="4" precision="12" unsigned="false" nullable="false"
                default="0" comment="MRP"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" name="PRIMARY">
            <column name="id"/>
        </constraint>
    </table>

    <table name="author_data" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="Author Table">
        <column xsi:type="smallint" name="id" padding="6" unsigned="false" nullable="false" identity="true" comment="Author ID"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="author_name" nullable="false" length="255" comment="Author Name"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="author_email" nullable="false" length="255" comment="Author Email"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="affliation" nullable="false" length="255" comment="Affliation"/>
        <column xsi:type="int" name="age" unsigned="true" nullable="true" identity="false" default="" comment="Age"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" name="PRIMARY">
            <column name="id"/>
        </constraint>
    </table>
</schema>
```

Now create **db_whitelist_schema.json** at same path

```
php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=Vendor_Module
```

After that just run **php bin/magento setup:upgrade**. For more information you can check [Here](https://cedcommerce.com/blog/declarative-schema-in-magento-2-3/) . Let me know in case you need more explanation on this.

Comment: But ... this is the same answer as above. Why double post?

Comment: @JisseReitsma I posted before above answer. check time of both answers.

Comment: My bad: Both of you answered the question within 14 minutes after the original post was made and you were just a bit quicker. It seems you guys make it a sport to answer a new question as soon as possible :)

Comment: The Answer is perfect. I want to add some information more :

The main disadvantage of the old approach(InstallSchema) is that Magento applies changes blindly. For example, in one version a new database column might be introduced, only to be removed in the next. Declarative setup eliminates this type of unnecessary work.

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2.3 core modules used a declarative schema approach instead of the setup upgrade script.
This is a new recommended approach in Magento 2.3 and above.
Magento 2.3.x is still working with InstallSchema, InstallData,.. etc.