# How to drop a table in Declarative schema?

Tags: database, magento2.3, magento2.3.0

How to drop a table in Magento 2.3.0 using declarative schema ?

Comment: what happens if you completely remove the table from the db_schema.xml file?

Answer (score 6):

Please follow below steps for drop table using **db_schema.xml** in Magento 2.3.X

> 1) Disable table

First of all, you need to add **disabled="true"** attribute in your table node.

```
<table name="abcd" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="Table" disabled="true">
```

> 2) Set blank table node

Remove all nodes in between table

```
<table name="abcd" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="Table" disabled="true">

</table>
```

> 3) Run commands

If you want to remove table so you must generate/update **db_schema_whitelist.json** in your module so please run below command before setup upgrade

```
1) php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=[Vendor_Module]

2) php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: thanks, you saved my time :)

Comment: WARNING: although being the right way of doing this, the `disabled=true` will NOT work if the original third-party module uses an InstallSchema.php script instead of the db_schema.xml new convention

Answer (score 0):

If you want to drop table, then you can either remove entire table node from xml file or you can set disabled attribute to true as like below line in your **db_schema.xml** :

```
<table name="rh_helloworld" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="RH Helloworld" disabled="true">
 ..
 </table>
```

[Resource](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/251886/17154)

Comment: I have checked its not working. Gettign Error: Element 'table', attribute 'disabled': The attribute 'disabled' is not allowed.
Line: 5
Verify the XML and try again.