# Magento 2.3 : Insert data into table using DeclarativeSchema

Tags: magento2.3, php-7.2

I have created upgrade data for insert the values for particular table

```
<?php

namespace XXX\YYY\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Upgrades DB for a module
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        /**
         * install product link attributes
         */
        $data = [
            [
                'link_type_id' => 'color',
                'product_link_attribute_code' => 'position',
                'data_type' => 'int',
            ]
        ];

        $setup->getConnection()
            ->insertMultiple($setup->getTable('catalog_product_link_attribute'), $data);

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

I need to change this script into Magento 2.3 (declarative schema)

how to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by magento db_schema concept?

Comment: need to change this script suitable for magento2.3

Comment: Did you use this answer? https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/251886/51810

Comment: I know ... But i need to insert the values for table ?

Comment: check this https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/migration-commands.html

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace XXX\YYY\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class AddCustomProductType implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
    )
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
    }

    public function apply()
    {
        /**
         * Install product link types
         */
        $data = [
            ['link_type_id' => \XXX\YYY\Model\Catalog\Product\Link::LINK_TYPE_COLORVARIANT, 'code' => 'colorvariant']
        ];

        foreach ($data as $bind) {
            $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->insertForce(
                $this->moduleDataSetup->getTable(
                    'catalog_product_link_type'
                ),
                $bind
            );
        }

        /**
         * install product link attributes
         */
        $data = [
            [
                'link_type_id' => \XXX\YYY\Model\Catalog\Product\Link::LINK_TYPE_COLORVARIANT,
                'product_link_attribute_code' => 'position',
                'data_type' => 'int',
            ]
        ];

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->insertMultiple(
            $this->moduleDataSetup->getTable('catalog_product_link_attribute'),
            $data
        );
    }

    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }

    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```