# How to create extension in Magento 2.3.3?

Tags: extensions, development, install-script, magento2.3.3

I am familiar with Magento 2 extension development but can anyone explain step by step extension development changes in Magento 2.3.3 by writing a simple "Hello_World" extension.

In Magento 2.3.x no more **setup** folder available and they just removed **installschema** and **upgradeschema** file, So the purpose behind this module development is to get proper knowledge and changelog for **Magento2.3.3** extension development.

I am still able to install and use some Magento 2.2.x extension in Magento 2.3.X So I'm not getting the exact mechanism behind this.

Can anyone help me remove my confusion, Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Can you provide a reference mentioning the removal of the setup folder?

Comment: @ Vivek Kumar, Please read here. 
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html

Comment: It mentions nowhere that setup folder and related scripts are going anywhere, it is just mentioning a new way to implement setup scripts i.e using declarative schema.
I don't think the setup folder is going anywhere till at least 2.x releases.

Comment: @ Vivek Kumar,  It Means we can still implement database structure using setup scripts?

Comment: yes, we can. I think it would be there till 3.x release to provide backward compatibility.

Comment: check this https://stagebit.com/magento-2/declarative-schema-magento-2-3/

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251884/magento-2-3-how-to-implement-declarative-schema-in-custom-module

Comment: @ Vivek Kumar & @ Sangeeta Chandaliya Thanks for the info