# How to create a custom table in Magento 2.3 using XML (Declarative Schema) and integrate in custom admin grid?

Tags: magento2.3, xml, declarative-schema, custom-admin-grid, database-schema

I need to create an admin grid and for that i need to create a custom table using Declarative Schema in Magento 2.3. How to create a custom table using declarative schema and integrate the table with my custom admin grid in Magento 2.3?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance..!

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Hi @AmitBera, Thanks for your reply. I had created a custom module and added the db_schema.xml file in etc directory, by referring this link: https://www.dckap.com/blog/declarative-schema-magento-2/. But the custom table which I had created was not created after running magento commands.

Comment: Check  magento devdocs https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html

Comment: I created db_schema.xml file and run the `php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=MyVendor_MyModule` before `setup:upgrade`. But the `db_whitelist_schema.json` was not created under etc directory of MyModule. I don't able to get that where I am going wrong?

Comment: dB whitelist scheme should run after set-up upgrade

Comment: Thanks @AmitBera, I created my .json file and database too. I was following this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/251886/84495 which indicates to create the json file before running the upgrade command.